# Nginx verify client certificate, but ignore expiration date

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have configured NGINX to very certificate which sent from a proxied server. It works correctly by combining 2 options

```
    proxy_ssl_verify on;
    proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate trusted_cers.pem;
```

However I would like to exclude the expiration date from the validation
step instead of verifying the whole certificate.

Is there any setup allowing this?
Thanks in advance for any suggestion of how to achieve this.